# Combining sampled videos from multiple sources using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

If I have two videos shooting the same subject but from different angles, and then I want to create a single video, but the combination is not just concatenation but a time lined sample linearly from each of the video to create the same time line output video. Is it possible?

For e.g. if both videos were shot for 1 minute each. then when I combine I want to combine 0-15 secs from 1st then 15-30 secs from second, then 30-45 from 1st, then 45-60 from second video. to create a 1 minute video.

Also as a generic case if above is possible, the time sample need not be uniformly distributed but random from each videos, as long as the total clips add upto original shoot time.

As a more generic case if above is possible, extending it to more than two video sources, lets say 3 videos combined in the above manner in a random time clips to create a single video.

many thanks
Mrunal

Comment: Can we assume that all videos are encoded with the same GOP structure and that you will cut only on I Frames?

Comment: Yes, for time being for simplicity, all the videos will use identical cameras to keep the encoding same and setup homogeneous. But if we assume the cameras differ slightly, as I know some HD web-cameras have onboard processing, while some not then how difficult it would be to achieve the similar results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by dividing your problem into this three subtasks:

1. Create 15 seconds chunks of each video.

you can do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 vid1_chunk_0.mp4
ffmpeg -y -i vid1.mp4 -vcodec copy -ss 00:00:15 -t 00:00:15 vid1_chunk_1.mp4
...
```

2. Create a simple text file with all the chunks in desired order like described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate).

This file (let us call it `list.txt`) should look like this:

```
file '/path/to/vid1_chunk_0.mp4'
file '/path/to/vid2_chunk_1.mp4'
file '/path/to/vid1_chunk_2.mp4'
...
```

3. Concatenate using: `ffmpeg -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy final.mp4`

Here is an example python script:

```py
import os

def sec2hms(seconds):
    m, s = divmod(seconds, 60)
    h, m = divmod(m, 60)
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)

def createchunks(video, vid_dur, chunk_dur):
    chunks = list()
    for n in range(0, vid_dur / chunk_dur):
        cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -v quiet'
        cmd += ' -i ' + video
        cmd += ' -vcodec copy'
        cmd += ' -ss ' + sec2hms(n*chunk_dur)
        cmd += ' -t ' + sec2hms(chunk_dur)
        cmd += ' ' + video[:-4] + '_chunk_' + str(n) + '.mp4'
        print cmd
        os.system(cmd)
        chunks.append(video[:-4] + '_chunk_' + str(n) + '.mp4')
    return chunks

# step 1. create 15 sec. chunks of first 60 sec. of content
vid1_chunks = createchunks('vid1.mp4', 60, 15)
vid2_chunks = createchunks('vid2.mp4', 60, 15)

# step 2. create a list.txt file (alternating order)
filenames = [None] * len(vid1_chunks)
filenames[::2] = vid1_chunks[::2]
filenames[1::2] = vid2_chunks[1::2]
with open('list.txt', 'w') as listfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        listfile.write('file \'' + fname + '\'\n')

# step 3. concatenate
cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -v quiet -f concat -i list.txt -c copy final.mp4'
os.system(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply and script. I sincerely appreciate it. I will take this to do some experimentation. I have some more things in mind that I will ask as I further in my experiments.

Comment: @MrunalGawade you're welcome. Try this out and if (and only if) this solves your problem don't forget to accept the answer, so the other people with the same problem could find the solution faster.

Comment: ok. But it might take me a bit to try this out since I am going out of station for couple of days. To accept answer I have to click on the up arrow of the answer on the left?

Comment: @MrunalGawade no this is for upvoting, you should upvote if you think that the answer is useful. And you should accept only if the provided answer solved your problem. You can read more about voting up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and about accepting [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Ok. So the script works :) I accepted the answer. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If frame accuracy isn't important, you can do this in two steps, skipping the chunk creation.

**Create concat list**

```
file 'video1.mp4'
inpoint 0
outpoint 15
file 'video2.mp4'
inpoint 15
outpoint 30
file 'video1.mp4'
inpoint 30
outpoint 45
file 'video2.mp4'
inpoint 45
outpoint 60
(fill out the text file in this manner...)
```

**Run concat**

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i list.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

Comment: I get the following error on execution above script.                                                                                                                           [concat @ 0xbf7ca0] Line 2: unknown keyword 'inpoint'
list.txt: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: ffmpeg version 2.7.2-1build1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers

Comment: Ok, that's July release. The range keywords were added later. Try a recent build.

Comment: ok. I will try that soon. thanks. I did "sudo apt-get install ffmpeg" on my ubuntu to install this version just couple of days back, so I will have to check with the manual source installation now.